# How to graphcool deploy on a shared cluster?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, backend, apollo, graphcool

I'm following a quickstart on the Graphcool tutorial for a basic hello world. When I try enter "graphcool deploy" and I select a shared cluster to deploy my app, nothing happens. It just hangs there. I'm not sure how to resolve this or properly deploy my app now. I dont want to have to install docker and try to deploy it locally.

I've waited for about 30 mins to see if anything happened and nothing did. I've searched through the internet to see if anyones run into this problem and I couldnt find anything.

[Image of trying to "graphcool deploy" using Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIKrd.png)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem!

Run this command:

```
gcf deploy -t prod -n your-project-name -c shared-eu-west-1
```

This worked for me!

Hope that helps.